# I've some hard time to understand method signatures in Objective-J / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax, cappuccino, objective-j

I've some hard time to understand method signatures in Objective-J (but it should be the same on Objective-C).

The syntax should be:

```
-(return_type)instanceMethod1:(param1_type)param1_varName :(param2_type)param2_varName;
```

The type is specified between parenthesis. However, I've found the following code line:

1)

```
var navigationArea = [[CPView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, CGRectGetHeight([contentView bounds]) - 150.0)];
```

Why are the parameters passed in between parenthesis ? I thought you specify parameters after a colon ":".

2)

```
-(void) importDocumentWithName:(NSString *)name withSpecifiedPreferences:(Preferences *)prefs beforePage:(int)insertPage;
```

what's "withSpecifiedPreferences" ? Is it the description ? What's the use of it ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** shows a mix of two styles, the Objective-C style method calls:

```
[[CPView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
```

and C-style function calls:

```
CGRectMake(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Objective-J is a strict super-set of JavaScript, which means that you can use the message-passing syntax in addition to the C-style function call syntax JavaScript has.

In **2)**, `withSpecifiedPreferences:` is part of the methods (or "selectors") name, see ["Message Syntax"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6).

Answer (score 1):

1. Because `CGRectMake()` and `CGRectGetHeight()` are C functions, not Objective-C or Objective-J methods. Parameters are passed comma-separated in parentheses for C function calls.

   The result of `CGRectMake()` is then passed as a parameter to the `initWithFrame:` method of the `CPView` class, which is an Objective-C method.
2. As for your second question I've not seen that method before so I can't really tell what the `prefs` parameter is used for...